# Java eclipse PAHO verify if publish was successful

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

```
MqttClient publisher = new MqttClient(MQTT_URL,clientId+configId);
MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
options.setCleanSession(true);
options.setConnectionTimeout(10);
publisher.connect(options);
MqttMessage msg = new MqttMessage(payload);
msg.setQos(0);
msg.setRetained(true);
publisher.publish(topic,msg);
```

I'm using the PAHO MQTT java library. In the code above, once the message is published, is there any callback available using which I can verify if the message was delivered to the broker?

Answer (score 0):

From the Paho [Javadoc](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback.html#messageArrived-java.lang.String-org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage-):

> **deliveryComplete**
>
> *void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token)*
>
> Called when delivery for a message has been completed, and all acknowledgments have been received. For QoS 0 messages it is called
> once the message has been handed to the network for delivery. For QoS
> 1 it is called when PUBACK is received and for QoS 2 when PUBCOMP is
> received. The token will be the same token as that returned when the
> message was published.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - token - the delivery token associated with the message.

You will need to implement the `MQTTCallback` interface and pass it to the client object with `.setCallback()` method ([docs](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/IMqttClient.html#setCallback-org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback-))

But at QOS 0 the callback will fire as soon as the client tries to send the message, there is no guarantee that the message will ever get there.

Comment: In case there is a connection loss and a publish was attempted, would this callback still be triggered?

Comment: For QOS 0 probably, Please read the doc on what the different QOS levels mean.

Comment: If you care about delivery you should not be using QOS 0